# Getting labels and classes from loaders data, but batc size is different

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

```
with torch.no_grad():
  for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(loaders_data['train']):
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)
```

this is my code my batch size is 32 but their lengths are different
i get this solutions

```
print(len(i))
print(len(labels))
print(len(inputs))
```

32
16
16

but i must get 32 for all. can you help me

i am making predictions for my machine learning homework. i am gettin activations or features from my model.

Comment: my train size is 1296 , but it only gets 32, i dont understand